# why can't I use do! when I want to ignore the result, in F#

Tags: f#

In the following code:

```
let! _ = 
    connection
    |> Sql.existingConnection
    |> Sql.query $"LISTEN \"{accountId}.{notificationName}\""
    |> Sql.executeNonQueryAsync
```

I ignore the result and I thought I could replace this by a *do!* statement, but then:

```
do! 
    connection
    |> Sql.existingConnection
    |> Sql.query $"LISTEN \"{accountId}.{notificationName}\""
    |> Sql.executeNonQueryAsync
```

will not compile:

> This expression was expected to have type 'int' but here has type 'unit'

and adding *|> ignore* at the end is not solving it. What would be the right way to do this?

---

edit:

here is the full code:

```
// start a loop, waiting for events
async {
    try
        // create a connection
        use connection = getConnection location

        // add the callback
        connection.Notification.Add (fun x -> callback (JObject.Parse x.Payload).["data"])

        // listen to the notifications
        let! _ =
            connection
            |> Sql.existingConnection
            |> Sql.query $"LISTEN \"{accountId}.{notificationName}\""
            |> Sql.executeNonQueryAsync

        // loop for events
        while true do
            try
                do! connection.WaitAsync()
            with ex ->
                error ex.Message
                Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.))
    with ex ->
        failwith $"{ex.Message}"
}
|> Async.StartAsTask
|> ignore
```

and the problem function (Sql.executeNonQueryAsync) is from this lib here: https://github.com/Zaid-Ajaj/Npgsql.FSharp/blob/50d3409fec844526e3c44901d64c8361b09e42a3/src/Npgsql.FSharp.fs (it's the last function of that file)

The lib is a F# wrapper around the Postgres' SQL client.

Comment: Have you tried `Async.Ignore`?

Comment: yes, it gives me error: A unique overload for method 'Source' could not be determined based on type information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed.

Comment: Hard to say then. I don't know what these types are, so it's just shooting in the dark without having something reproducible.

Comment: @PhillipCarter, the last call returns a Task<int>; but yes, this seems quite odd to me.

Comment: If you want to get this answered, you'll need to specify what the `Sql` module is (some library?), where exactly are you getting the errro (what line?) and also what is the computation expression builder you're using (task or async?) Without this, it's impossible to know...

Comment: As Tomas said, You need to specify what the Sql module comes from, and what CE builder you are using to get a proper answer.  But I guess that your last statement gives some monadic construct of int. (Task<int>, Transaction<int> or similar) that your CE can resolve. To use `do!` you need to end upp with Task<unit> (or whatever monad you are using). To achieve that you must map the int to unit. Try adding `|> map ignore` or to be more verbose `|>map (fun _i -> ())`

Comment: I've added the full code as well as a link to the call I'm doing in the problem function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the `Task<'T>` to `Task` using the `:>` Operator.

```ml
do! 
    connection
    |> Sql.existingConnection
    |> Sql.query $"LISTEN \"{accountId}.{notificationName}\""
    |> Sql.executeNonQueryAsync
    :> Task
```

you can also make it consistent with `Async.Ignore` using the following extension

```ml
open System.Threading.Tasks
type Task with
    static member Ignore (t: Task<'T>) =
        t :> Task
```

so that it becomes

```ml
do! 
    connection
    |> Sql.existingConnection
    |> Sql.query $"LISTEN \"{accountId}.{notificationName}\""
    |> Sql.executeNonQueryAsync
    |> Task.Ignore
```

Comment: using :> Task will also not compile: A unique overload for method 'Source' could not be determined based on type information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed.

Comment: `Source` doesn't appear anywhere in your code, so it seems like that error might be a separate problem?

Comment: Something doesn't add up, just realized that your code snippet uses `async` computation expression but the library in question returns a `Task<'T>` so there's no way the original code with `let! _` worked without first piping to `Async.AwaitTask`

Try adding the `|> Async.AwaitTask` at the end of the solution.